# Getting the current active tab in google chrome, using python

Tags: python, google-chrome

I'm very new to python and I wish I could do this one.

I wish to get the url of the current active tab in my google chrome through my python code.

Are there any easy way to do this? Any lib?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @katrielalex: Ubuntu 12.04